# Emscripten: setjmp/longjmp fails but runs when compiled natively

Tags: c, llvm, webassembly, emscripten

Ref: https://fanf.livejournal.com/105413.html

TL;DR: Is there a difference between how SJLJ works when compiled with GCC and when compiled with LLVM/Emscripten?

I tried to run the following code both in the browser and on command-line. In the first case it crashes the moment I try to jump to a previously created point:

```
spawning 1
coroutine 1 at 0x67cbb4 arg 0x7e8
jumping to 0
spawning 2
coroutine 2 at 0x67bbb4 arg 0x7e8
jumping to 0
spawning 3
coroutine 3 at 0x67abb4 arg 0x7e8
jumping to 2
> Exception thrown: longjmp
```

Whereas when compiling with GCC I get:

```
spawning 1
coroutine 1 at 0x7fffeef84048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e0
jumping to 0
spawning 2
coroutine 2 at 0x7fffeef83048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e0
jumping to 0
spawning 3
coroutine 3 at 0x7fffeef82048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e0
jumping to 0
spawning 4
coroutine 4 at 0x7fffeef81048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e0
jumping to 3
coroutine 3 at 0x7fffeef82048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e1
jumping to 1
coroutine 1 at 0x7fffeef84048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e2
jumping to 3
coroutine 3 at 0x7fffeef82048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e3
jumping to 2
coroutine 2 at 0x7fffeef83048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e4
jumping to 0
spawning 5
coroutine 5 at 0x7fffeef80048 arg 0x7f1ffdde94e0
jumping to 4
> runs forever
```

Comment: Could this be related to `we support proper setjmp/longjmp, i.e., jumping down the stack, but not jumping up to an unwound stack, which is undefined behavior` ?

Comment: Link for @YanickSalzmann's comment: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/guidelines/portability_guidelines.html#code-that-cannot-be-compiled

Comment: I think that might be the case - although it would be nice to get a specific confirmation for clarification.

Comment: http://troubles.md/posts/why-do-we-need-the-relooper-algorithm-again/ seems to provide a clearer answer. I'd be happy to mark the question as answered using this link if others think it's a good idea.